# bootstrap4 carousel transition shows both images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So, I cannot figure out why the bootstrap4 transition momentarily displays both of my images with their captions, one on top of the other, during the transition and then behaves normally.  Here is my code:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryUI-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryUI-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css">
</head>

<body>
  ...

  <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade w-100" id="featured" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item m-auto">
        <img class="d-block  m-auto" src="images/pic1.png" alt="Convoluted Excel ">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> Some text... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item m-auto">
        <img class="d-block m-auto " src="images/pic2.png" alt="Excel Prone to errors">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> Some text... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item m-auto active">
        <img class="d-block m-auto " src="images/pic3.png" alt="Clear dashboard">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> Some text... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

I compared my code with the docs and W3School, but cannot trouble-shoot this odd behavior.  Also the caption shows up with a grey background. Is this normal or am I overriding the bootstrap4 class somewhere in my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `m-auto` class causing the issue. Remove it and it shall work properly.
Change all three `<div class="carousel-item m-auto">` to `<div class="carousel-item">`

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryUI-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryUI-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css">-->
</head>

<body>
  ...

  <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade w-100" id="featured" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block  m-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/id/500/400/300" alt="Convoluted Excel ">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> Some text... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block m-auto " src="https://picsum.photos/id/600/400/300" alt="Excel Prone to errors">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> Some text... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block m-auto " src="https://picsum.photos/id/700/400/300" alt="Clear dashboard">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <p> Some text... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @yinsweet, but how did you trouble-shoot that?

Comment: @EarlyCoder I just compared with the example given by Bootstrap-4 Documentation and try to remove the class which is not used by the example.

Comment: sweet! You'd think their classes work fine with each other

Comment: Because the example is working fine, then I think there might be something extra causing the issue.